# Django Python 1.5.1 throwing import error

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and following the tutorial mentioned in this link:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html

Everything goes well till I come to the Chapter 3, section of creating the Hello World:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html

I believe I have followed everything to the letter - but when I try to access the site:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`

I get the following error:

ImportError at /hello/

No module named views

Here is the traceback information for this error:

---

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "E:\DPF\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "E:\DPF\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "E:\DPF\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "E:\DPF\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "E:\DPF\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "E:\Work\Documents\Sites\mysite\mysite\urls.py" in <module>
  2. from mysite.views import hello

Exception Type: ImportError at /hello/
Exception Value: No module named views
```

---

The directory structure is as follows:

```
mysite--
    mysite--
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
        settings.py
        settings.pyc
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        wsgi.py
        wsgi.pyc
    django.db
    manage.py
    views.py
```

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Regards,
Indrajit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you added `<appname>` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

still errror then,

if you run `django-admin.py startapp <appneam>` from the project folder(`\<mainfolder>\<projectfolder>`)

the you want to try:

```
from <yourprojectname>.<yourappname>.views import hello
```

or you run `django-admin.py startapp <appneam>` from the folder contains manage.py(ie the `\<mainfolder>\`).

then do all the nessasary steps and then try:

```
from <yourappname>.views import hello
```

**actually the djangobook is old and not updated frequently.**

Comment: I hadn't since there is no app that I am creating. I am simply creating views.py and placing it in the same location where manage.py is kept.

Comment: oh sorry, then try: `from <yourprojectname>.<yourappname>.views import hello` or `from <yourappname>.views import hello` can i know the directory structure

Comment: Have updated the post with my directory structure. In my urls.py file, I already have the line:

`from mysite.views import hello`

Comment: hey move `view.py` into `mysite\mysite` folder ie the folder contains `setitings, url.py etc` then surely it will work

Comment: That worked great!! Thanks a lot. You are right, that djangobook is not updated. Can you suggest any good book for the latest version?

Comment: djangobook is a very good book i studied upto chapter 13. but some errors may be found which can be fixed by refering   
docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5 (because django book is not updated)